# What is a "shutout" in Dropshot?

Tags: achievements, rocket-league

One of the new achievements is

> **Damage Control**
>   Win a Dropshot match via shutout

What is a "shutout"?  I've played (and won) a few games of Dropshot, but I don't remember ever seeing something called that.

Comment: In some games, a "shutout" refers to winning without having the opposing team score any points. Not sure if that is the case here though.

Comment: @Angzuril Is correct that shutouts refer to winning while "shutting out" your opponents. It's about winning the game without letting the other team score at all. 5-0, 3-0 1-0 whatever the final score may be as long as they have not scored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutout)

> In team sports, a shutout  is a game in which one team prevents the other from scoring any points

Specific videos claiming a shutout in Rocket League Dropshot [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIYr24kqAlQ) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T4v5najBX0).

The first video claims this is all that's needed for the achievement, however the second video description says it was not enough to gain the achievement.

Comment: Is it possible to get a shutout in gamemodes outside of Dropshot?

Comment: It would be possible to have a shutout, but that would not give the achievement for "win a **dropshot** match via shutout"

Comment: Easy way to get the achievement [here](https://www.trueachievements.com/a231674/damage-control-achievement)

Answer (score -1):

To get a shutout in Dropshot the opposing team must not destroy or even make the ball, when in there control, touch 1 of your tiles.  Any easy way to do this is, to go on (from main menu) play, play local, exhibition, make the game mode dropshot, put on no bots, any score one or more goals to win, unless they patch this it works.

Comment: This is conflicting with both the other answer and my experience.  Do you have a source?